# Задать hover для svg иконки заданной с помощью object

Tags: svg

Cтолкнулась с проблемой невозможности добавить hover для svg иконки
html:

```
<div class="footer__social">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/social/003-linkedin.svg" class="footer__facebook"></object>
</div>
```

css:

```
&__social
    display: inline
    &__facebook
        height: 50px
        width: 50px
        fill:inherit 
        stroke:inherit
        &:hover
            fill: yellow
```

svg:

```
<svg height="512pt" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m256 0c-141.363281 0-256 114.636719-256 256s114.636719 256 256 256 256-114.636719 256-256-114.636719-256-256-256zm-74.390625 387h-62.347656v-187.574219h62.347656zm-31.171875-213.1875h-.40625c-20.921875 0-34.453125-14.402344-34.453125-32.402344 0-18.40625 13.945313-32.410156 35.273437-32.410156 21.328126 0 34.453126 14.003906 34.859376 32.410156 0 18-13.53125 32.402344-35.273438 32.402344zm255.984375 213.1875h-62.339844v-100.347656c0-25.21875-9.027343-42.417969-31.585937-42.417969-17.222656 0-27.480469 11.601563-31.988282 22.800781-1.648437 4.007813-2.050781 9.609375-2.050781 15.214844v104.75h-62.34375s.816407-169.976562 0-187.574219h62.34375v26.558594c8.285157-12.78125 23.109375-30.960937 56.1875-30.960937 41.019531 0 71.777344 26.808593 71.777344 84.421874zm0 0"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте этот файл в `редакторе кода` - между тегами `svg` добавьте ещё два тега

```
<defs>
  <style></style>
</defs>
```

и внутри напишите что при наведении вы хотите заменить заливку и даже задержку анимации

```
<defs>
  <style>
    svg{fill: #000; transition: 0.34s}
    svg:hover{ fill: red;}
 </style>
</defs>
```

`object` ведёт себя как `iframe` и потому некоторые манипуляции с контентом внутри не возможны

Если требуется применять большое количество иконок но лень открывать каждый и писать `defs style` то можно руками собрать спрайт и использовать не `object` а `use` и в этом случае можно манипулировать `svg` но можно собрать спрайт сборщиком типа webpack или gulp и уже этими средствами работать с наведением

Вот [здесь по этой ссылке](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)  [автор сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt) подробно описал все способы подключения `svg` к странице